# Including ampersand in URL in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I have a page name that does not include an ampersand, but I need its URL to inluce one. I have tried using %26, which changes the url in page editor, but does not really create a proper URL.

Is there a need for some plugin or can it be done simplier?

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Yes i did, it just keeps skipping it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to comply with HTML specifications, you need to encode all special characters (not only ampersands) in URL.

See the official table [here](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) with all character encodings.

This can be done manually, or automatically with PHP function [urlencode()](http://www.php.net/urlencode).

Comment: well I have tried to type in all of the possible ways: &#38; &amp; %26 %38, but as soon as I click on OK in the edit field, the character is skipped

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about javascript inside post/page... `\u0026` works!